# Overflow on centered div won't hide

Tags: html, css, overflow

And yes, the parent container's position is relative.

I'm trying to create a kind of ripple effect by having several circles expand out from a single point in all directions until they're expanded beyond the viewport.

So I've got a few divs that are circle shaped and absolutely positioned. They are centered as shown below. I have a click handler that adds the `grow` class which increases the width and height of the divs to expand them. When the circles expand beyond the viewport, the y-overflow hides just fine but not the x-overflow. Can't figure out what gives.

It might be worth noting that when the circle hits the left edge of the viewport, it only continues to expand out in all other directions; the left edge of the window seems to be a boundary it can't cross.

```
<body>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</body>
```

```
body {
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grow {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 2000px;
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```
$(".circle").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("grow");
});
```

Comment: you have some html for us?

Comment: Questions asking to debug code require an [MCVE].  There has to be enough code here to reproduce the problem.  Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issue, **only post the compiled CSS** (and the necessary markup).

Comment: Thanks! Sorry about that. HTML added, though it's pretty basic markup.

Comment: Cannot reproduce a problem here with the provided code: https://jsfiddle.net/e5Lhy7r2/

Comment: what you want to do can you show a image of what you expect?

Comment: Still cannot reproduce anything with the amended code: https://jsfiddle.net/e5Lhy7r2/2/.  It is impossible to help when you're not providing code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I added more code. Hopefully it's a bit clearer. I'm just trying to do a simple transition where a circle expands out from its center, while staying centered on the page, until it has expanded beyond the viewport. Obviously with the code above all circles will expand at the same time, but in I'm using a timer in my JS.

Comment: No, nothing is obvious here.  We are not mind readers, we can't see all of the code you have on your screen.  All we can see is exactly what's in that little jsfiddle, which is a whole lot of nothing plus a random class thrown in that isn't related at all.  You have to provide the code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Not obvious to you, perhaps. But the answer below works! Just a relatively simple styling mishap ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely-positioned elements larger than the viewport don't get centered *relative to their own size* when you set 'top', 'right', 'bottom', and 'left' to all be zero. You'll need to set the element to be centered relative to its own size, and set `overflow: hidden` on its parent. One way to do that would be to set `left:` to `50%`, then `margin-left:` to be one-half of the element's size. Like so:

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.grow {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 2000px;
  height: 2000px;
  margin-left: -1000px;
}
```

I think this does what you're talking about. See [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/ianm/pen/bpKQvd).

Comment: That did the trick! I just added a top of 50%, adjusted for the margin there as well, and got the effect I wanted. Thanks!